# Compile tvm with bazel can't involve llvm

Tags: clang, bazel, llvm-c++-api, bazel-cpp, tvm

I tried to compile TVM with bazel, but block in src/target/llvm.
Here is my TVM bazel BUILD file

```
cc_library(
name = "llvm_compiler",
srcs = glob([
    "src/target/llvm/*.cc",
]),
hdrs = glob([
    "src/target/llvm/*.h",
    "src/target/*.h",
]),
deps = [
    "//3rdparty/clang+llvm-9.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-16.04:llvm",
    ":compiler_hdrs",
    ":runtime_hdrs",
    ":arith_hdrs",
    ":implicit_hdrs",
    ":tir_hdrs",
],
copts = [
    "-DTVM_LLVM_VERSION=90",
    "-O0",
],
# alwayslink = True,
linkstatic = True,
visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
```

And I add this file into clang+llvm-9.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-16.04.tar.gz which download from web

```
cc_library(
    name = "llvm",
    srcs = glob([
        "lib/libLLVMXRay.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMWindowsManifest.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMTextAPI.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMTableGen.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMSymbolize.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMDebugInfoPDB.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMOrcJIT.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMJITLink.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMObjectYAML.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMMCA.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMLTO.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMPasses.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMObjCARCOpts.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMLineEditor.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMLibDriver.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMInterpreter.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMFuzzMutate.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMMCJIT.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMExecutionEngine.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMRuntimeDyld.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMDlltoolDriver.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMOption.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMDebugInfoGSYM.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMCoverage.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMCoroutines.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMXCoreDisassembler.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMXCoreCodeGen.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMXCoreDesc.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMXCoreInfo.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMX86Disassembler.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMX86AsmParser.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMX86CodeGen.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMX86Desc.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMX86Utils.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMX86Info.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMWebAssemblyDisassembler.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMWebAssemblyCodeGen.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMWebAssemblyDesc.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMWebAssemblyAsmParser.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMWebAssemblyInfo.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMSystemZDisassembler.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMSystemZCodeGen.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMSystemZAsmParser.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMSystemZDesc.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMSystemZInfo.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMSparcDisassembler.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMSparcCodeGen.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMSparcAsmParser.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMSparcDesc.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMSparcInfo.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMRISCVDisassembler.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMRISCVCodeGen.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMRISCVAsmParser.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMRISCVDesc.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMRISCVUtils.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMRISCVInfo.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMPowerPCDisassembler.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMPowerPCCodeGen.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMPowerPCAsmParser.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMPowerPCDesc.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMPowerPCInfo.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMNVPTXCodeGen.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMNVPTXDesc.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMNVPTXInfo.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMMSP430Disassembler.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMMSP430CodeGen.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMMSP430AsmParser.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMMSP430Desc.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMMSP430Info.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMMipsDisassembler.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMMipsCodeGen.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMMipsAsmParser.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMMipsDesc.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMMipsInfo.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMLanaiDisassembler.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMLanaiCodeGen.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMLanaiAsmParser.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMLanaiDesc.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMLanaiInfo.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMHexagonDisassembler.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMHexagonCodeGen.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMHexagonAsmParser.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMHexagonDesc.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMHexagonInfo.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMBPFDisassembler.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMBPFCodeGen.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMBPFAsmParser.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMBPFDesc.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMBPFInfo.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMARMDisassembler.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMARMCodeGen.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMARMAsmParser.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMARMDesc.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMARMUtils.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMARMInfo.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMAMDGPUDisassembler.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMAMDGPUCodeGen.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMMIRParser.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMipo.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMInstrumentation.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMVectorize.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMLinker.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMIRReader.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMAsmParser.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMAMDGPUAsmParser.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMAMDGPUDesc.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMAMDGPUUtils.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMAMDGPUInfo.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMAArch64Disassembler.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMMCDisassembler.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMAArch64CodeGen.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMGlobalISel.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMSelectionDAG.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMAsmPrinter.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMDebugInfoDWARF.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMCodeGen.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMTarget.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMScalarOpts.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMInstCombine.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMAggressiveInstCombine.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMTransformUtils.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMBitWriter.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMAnalysis.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMProfileData.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMObject.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMBitReader.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMBitstreamReader.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMCore.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMRemarks.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMAArch64AsmParser.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMMCParser.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMAArch64Desc.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMMC.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMDebugInfoCodeView.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMDebugInfoMSF.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMBinaryFormat.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMAArch64Utils.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMAArch64Info.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMSupport.a", 
        "lib/libLLVMDemangle.a",
        ]),
    hdrs = glob([
        "include/**/*.h",
        "include/**/*.def",
        "include/**/*.inc",
        ]),
    strip_include_prefix = "include",
    includes = ["include"],  # 添加包含目录，这样在源文件中就可以直接引用头文件
    copts = [
        "-lz",
        "-lrt",
        "-ldl",
        "-ltinfo",
        "-lpthread",
        "-lm",
        "-lxml2",
        "-D_GNU_SOURCE",
        "-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS",
        "-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS",
        "-D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS",
        "-DDMLC_USE_FOPEN64=0",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

When I run this libtvm.so, it complain that:

```
TVMError: Check failed: bf != nullptr: target.build.llvm is not enabled
```

So I change llvm_compiler as alwayslink=true, but it complain

```
OSError: lib/libtvm.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN4llvm6legacy11PassManagerE
```

And I tried this thread: [Building LLVM with Bazel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51585688/building-llvm-with-bazel), with code : https://github.com/dgp1130/llvm-bazel-foolang, but the error reported is same.

Everything works fine on CMake, I don't know what's different with Bazel. And actually, I only hope "TVM_REGISTER_GLOBAL("target.build.llvm")" not delelte by gcc.

Thanks!